# Вывод результата по нескольким условиям

Tags: python, visual-studio

У меня стоит следующая задача:

> Создайте программу "Медицинская анкета", где вы запросите у пользователя такие данные, как имя, фамилию, возраст, и вес.
> Выведите результат, согласно которому пациент в хорошем состоянии, если ему до 30 лет и вес от 50 и до 120 кг;
> Пациенту требуется начать вести правильный образ жизни, если ему более 30 и вес меньше 50 или больше 120 кг;
> Пациенту требуется врачебный осмотр, если ему более 40 и вес менее 50 или больше 120 кг.

```
good = 'хорошее состояние!'
normal = 'следует заняться собой!'
bad = 'следует обратиться к врачу!'
    
print ('med card 1.0')
        
age = int(input('how old are u? : '))
weight = float(input('ur weight : '))
if age <= 30 and weight >= 50 <= 120:
    print(good)
elif age > 30 and weight < 50 > 120:
    print (normal)
else:
    print(bad)
```

У меня возникают проблемы с выводом результата `bad`, всегда выводит `good` или `normal`.
Также, как можно лучше сократить код в плане строк.
Извиняюсь, если задаю глупые вопросы.

Comment: Условия какие-то кривые. Например нет варианта `age <= 30 and weight <50`. Было бы логичным выводить вариант `bad`, но в описании `bad` сказано, что он для возраста больше 40. Если же условия действительно такие, то запишите проверку веса в виде: `50 <= weight <= 120`  или `weight < 50 or weight > 120`

Answer (score 1):

```
if age <= 30 and weight >= 50 <= 120:
    print(good)
elif age > 30 and weight < 50 > 120:
    print (normal)
else:
    print(bad)
```

потому что вы уж очень вольно распорядились сложными условиями

ведь по `else` у вас "все плохо" вывелось для всех остальных, чем прошедшим 1) или 2) условия

а в задаче конкретно говорится

> возраст больше 40 и весь меньше 50 или больше 120

посмотрите что у вас будет если возраст больше 40, а весь 100кг - посмотрите - у вас выведется "плохо"

поэтому в данной задаче не надо делать `ilif` - сделайте просто 3 условия `if` ну или вместо `else` сделайте еще `elif` и впишите третье условие, а уж потом сделайте `else` Для остальных, кто не попал ни в один из трех критериев

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно правильно проверять условия:

```
good = 'хорошее состояние!'
normal = 'следует заняться собой!'
bad = 'следует обратиться к врачу!'
print('med card 1.0')

age = int(input('how old are u? : '))
weight = float(input('ur weight : '))
if weight < 50 or weight > 120: # проверяем вес
    if age >= 40: # условие для тех, кто старше 40
        print(bad)
    elif age >= 30: # или для тех, кто старше 30
        print(normal)
else:
    print(good)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
weight >= 50 <= 120
```

Такое условие эквивалентно следующему:

```
weight >= 50 and 50 <= 120
```

То есть оно проверит только `weight >= 50`, а вторая часть будет всегда `True`.

Правильно же условие можно записать вот так:

```
50 <= weight <= 120
```

Это будет сокращённая запись для такого условия:

```
50 <= weight and weight <= 120
```

А в целом, как правильно замечено в комментариях, задача кривая: если вес у пациента выходит за обозначенные границы и ему меньше 30 лет, то непонятно, что выводить в этом случае.